# Send mail on Checkin to VSS 6.0

Tags: email, visual-sourcesafe, commit

Is there a way to send mail to a list of users when files are checkedin to VSS 6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be something here for it:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/VBVSSAddin.aspx